# Continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've been trying to work this problem out I feel like I can't even figure out where to start. I was hoping someone could walk me through this.

**Justify**: The definition of continuity of any function $f: D\to R$ at a point a point $a \in D$ is equivalent to (i.e., true if and only if) the following statement holding:

The preimage under $f$ of any open interval containing $f(a)$ (i.e. $f^{-1} ((g,h)),$ where $g<f(a) <h$) contains the intersection of $D$ with some open interval $(c, d)$ containing $a$ (i.e., $(c,d)$ intersect $D$ is a subset of $f^{-1}((g,h)),$ where $c<a<d$).

Comment: Is $D$ a subset of the real numbers? Given that you've tagged it real analysis, I'd say it appears so.

Comment: Yes, $D$ is a subset of the reals.

Comment: I think, this would help 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61941/continuous-function-and-open-set

Comment: Is there anyway you could explain it to me by step?